# How to rerrange the context menu of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

I want to move my *Refresh* button to the top. How can I do it?

[image]

I’m using Nautilus Action Congif Tools and `nautilus -q`.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to change the application source code and rebuild it from scratch. GTK applications compiled from source code to machine language like Nautilus rarely provide a mechanism to change menu layouts on the fly.